# Navigate to a specific table/view in list of objects in Microsoft Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, odbc

When setting up a Microsoft Query connection (to an Oracle table/view via ODBC) in Excel 2016:

[image]

[image]

---

**Problem:**

I have hundreds of Oracle views to scroll through in order to get to the view that I want:

[image]

Manually scrolling through that many views is tedious, especially when adding multiple connections to a spreadsheet.

---

**Question:**

Is there an easier way to navigate to a **specific** view in the list of objects in Microsoft Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is yes.

If I click a view in the list, then type the first few letters of the view name that I want, then the list will navigate to that view.

For example, I want to navigate to a view called LTIP_RD_COND_CURRENT_VW. So if I type "LTIP", then the list navigates to that view.

[image]

That's much more convenient than manually scrolling through the list.